# X509Certificate Java Class equivalent in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, certificate, x509

within Java, to gather the user's certs, you could achieve this by:

```
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

From there, you could check the validity using the checkValidity method for each particular cert in the array.  In Rails/Ruby, is there a similar way to gather the user's certs?

Similarly, you could establish your trust and key stores via

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/to/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/truststore");
```

Where in Rails can I establish the key/trust stores or is completely dependent on the server?

Comment: Look around(google, github) for a gem/plugin that does what you have mentioned. I don't think that a language needs that functionality built in. That's what gems are for.

Comment: So it looks like both questions depend on the server.  My project is using Apache with Phusion Passenger.  To acquire specific attributes from the cert, such as the distinguished name, you can simply do dn = request.env['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN']  That's exactly what I'm looking for.  For question 2, the "openssl" gem may be useful.  Anyone's 2 cents are welcome.